# Why am I getting conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

Tags: language-design, bison, flex-lexer

I'm new to bison and I'm getting a "conflicts: 1 shift/reduce" error. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's the y file.

test.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define YYERROR_VERBOSE
#define YYDEBUG 1
void yyerror(const char *str);
int yywrap();
%}

%union
{
    int integer;
    char *string;
}

%token <string>     VAR_LOCAL
%token <integer>    LIT_NUMBER
%token <string>     LIT_STRING
%token WS_LINEBRK

//%token SYMB_EQL
%token SYMB_PLUS
%token SYMB_MINUS
%token SYMB_MUL
%token SYMB_DIV

%%

/*
    // Sample input
    num = 10
    str = "this is a string"
*/

inputs: /* empty token */
        | literal
        | variable
        | inputs stmt WS_LINEBRK
        ;

stmt:   variable "=" exps  
        ;

exps:   variable op literal
        | variable op variable
        | literal op literal
        | literal op variable
        ;


op:     SYMB_PLUS | SYMB_MINUS | SYMB_MUL | SYMB_DIV ;


variable: VAR_LOCAL
        {
            printf("variable: %s\n", $1);
        }
        ;

literal:
        number | string
        ;

string: LIT_STRING
        {
            printf("word: %s\n", $1);
        }
        ;

number: LIT_NUMBER
        {
        printf("number: %d\n", $1);
        }
        ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 

main()
{
    yyparse();
}
```

Here's the lex file
test.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include "y.tab.h"
int line_no = 0;

%}

%%
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*       {
                            // local variable
                            yylval.string=strdup(yytext);
                            return VAR_LOCAL;
                        }

[0-9]+                  {
                            //number literal
                            yylval.integer=atoi(yytext);
                            return LIT_NUMBER;
                        }

=                       return SYMB_EQL;
\+                      return SYMB_PLUS;
\-                      return SYMB_MINUS;
\*                      return SYMB_MUL;
\/                      return SYMB_DIV;


\"[-+\!\.a-zA-Z0-9' ]+\"    {
                            // word literal
                            yylval.string=strdup(yytext);
                            return LIT_STRING;
                        }

\n                      {
                            // line break
                            printf("\n");
                            return WS_LINEBRK;
                        }

[ \t]+                  /* ignore whitespace */;

%%
```

Comment: I've noticed that moving the "| literal" and "| variable" rules from the inputs production to stmt production makes the error go away...but I don't understand why...

Comment: See my reply. Moving the `variable` rule to `stmt` allows bison to resolve all situations with just one lookahead token: Now it just matches `variable`. If it's followed by `"="` (lookahead token used here), it matches the assignment rule. If not, it matches the `variable` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bison -r test.y` will write a file `test.output` with a detailed description of the generated state machine that allows you to see what's going on - such as the state where the shift/reduce conflict occurs.

In your case, the problem is in the start state (corresponding to your start nonterminal, `inputs`). Say the first token is VAR_LOCAL. There's two things your parser could do:

- It could match the `variable` case.
- It could also match the `inputs stmt WS_LINEBRK` case: `inputs` matches the empty string (first line), and `stmt` matches `variable "=" exps`.

With the one token of lookahead that bison parsers use, there's no way to tell. You need to change your grammar to get rid of this case.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the grammar, as Fabian has suggested, move the *variable* and *literal* to the end of *exps* from *inputs*

```
inputs: 
    | variable
    | literal 

exps:
...
    | variable
    | literal
```

That allows `x= y`,`x="aliteral"` syntax.

To allow for empty input lines, change the `/* empty token */` rule to `WS_LINEBREAK`:

```
inputs: WS_LINEBRK
    | stmt WS_LINEBRK
    | inputs stmt WS_LINEBRK
    ;
```

On another note, since the scanner still looks for the *SYMB*_ *EQUAL* ; but the parser no longer defines it (its commented out), something needs to be done in order to compile.  One option is to uncomment the `%token` definition  and use *SYMB*_ *EQUAL* instead of the literal "=" in the parser .y file.

Comment: I had put back SYMB_EQUAL in the parser as I couldn't get it to work otherwise. I was expecting it to work since I seen examples online (for example Exp: Term "+" Term) that had similar production rules.